# html css background overlay

Tags: html, css

I already have a backround and what Im trying to do is put a white block on it and text/images inside, like here - http://dzconstructions.co.uk

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945818/overlay-background-image-onto-background-color

Comment: Just put div with elements(text, images) inside block with background.

Answer (score 2):

Much better to avoid inline styles and place the following in a separate style sheet...

```
body {
  background-image:url(/background-image.png);
}

div {
  width:500px; 
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

div's should help you to realize this. Just put the background upon the body and insert a div with background-color white. You may then insert the content/images into this div.

example:

```
<body style="background-image:url(/background-image.gif)">
<div style="width:500px; height: 200px;">
YOUR CONTENT AND IMAGES HERE
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to put background

```
body {
    background: transparent url("Images/Background.png");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then use Divs to add white block on it